# How to install substrate-validator-set pallet

Tags: substrate

I'm trying to install substrate-validator-set pallet with substrate 3.0.0 monthly-2021-05:

```
git clone -b v3.0.0+monthly-2021-05 --depth 1 https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template
```

But when I do a cargo build --release it give me a lot of errors, I post all errors on github: https://github.com/gautamdhameja/substrate-validator-set/issues/8

Answer (score 2):

There are breaking changes between the release of the template and this pallet you are trying to use. You need to modify the pallet to use updated dependencies and fix build issues that come up when you do. Or you can use the template of the same v3.0.0 release for your node.